# Search JSON array data - Case independence

Tags: json, search, lowercase

I am using the following statement to search a JSON array :

```
var result = residentData.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).some(val => val.includes(search)));
```

`residentData` is the array data in JSON format. "search" is the string I'm searching for. 
I'd like to do the search independent of the case (upper, low, mix) of the search string. I've tried `toLowerCase()` but haven't been successful.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use localComparer with sesitivity option as base like follows

```
'First'.localeCompare('first', { sensitivity: 'base' })); // 0
```

[More information about localComparer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: I added a second "answer" since I couldn't fit my comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointer to `localeCompare()`.  I went through the MDN explanation, but being relatively new to Javascript, I'm not getting it to work.  Maybe if I gave you more code details, you could show me how to use `localeCompare`?

The JSON data looks like this:

```
var residentData=[{
    "FirstName": "fname1",
    "LastName": "lname1",
    "Street": "Street1 Lane",
    "Phone": "12345",
    "MobilePhone": "45643",
    "EMail": "person1@email.com"
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "Deborah",
    "LastName": "Secondname",
    "Street": "335 Street2 Lane",
    "Phone": "1235",
    "MobilePhone": "93847",
    "EMail": "person2@email2.com"
  }]
```

I plan on allowing users to enter a search term (var = searchWord).  I'd like to use localeCompare to take that searchWord variable and search for strings inside the array regardless of case.  Then, if the string is found in one of the  array objects it will display all string:value pairs in that object. I hope I've described all this clear enough so it makes sense.